# How do I extract a class from this HTML with XPath

Tags: xpath

```html
<div class="a-row a-spacing-micro" style="">
  <i class="a-icon a-icon-star-medium a-star-medium-4"></i>
  <a data-analytics="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Review.FullReview&quot;}" class="a-size-base a-link-normal a-color-base review-title a-text-bold" href="/gp/cdp/member-reviews/A19123D9G66E0O/ref=pdp_new_read_full_review_link?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1&amp;sort_by=MostRecentReview#R1Z0A6K9CROFFV">      <span>Good Cheap Knee Pads</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have this HTML that I am scraping with XPath. What XPath would I use to just return the class "a-star-medium-4"?

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: do you need the class name of "a" tag? show your xpath that you have tried.

Comment: @gp.

I'm using this XPath as a selector for a table: 
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/i

And I'm using this XPath as a selector for a Column:
//i/@class

It is returning "nav-icon"

I'd just like it to return the text "a-star-medium-4" Thanks!

Comment: 1st - for xpath, class is just like any other attribute so you will get the full string in class attribute value. you will have to split the string to extract classes. 2nd - on a side note, use a simpler xpath e.g. //div/i/@class or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for this specific HTML, you can extract the class name starting with `a-star` with this XPath:

```
substring(string(//i/@class),string-length(substring-before(string(//i/@class),'a-star')) +1)
```

When applied to your example HTML this returns `a-star-medium-4`.
As explanation: `string(//i/@class)` returns the class attribute value `a-icon a-icon-star-medium a-star-medium-4`. To get *only* the class name starting with `a-star`, `substring()` is used to remove the part of the string *before* `a-star` by cutting the string *after* the `string-length()` of the remaining string when it's cutted *before* `a-star` using `substring-before()`.